# Show that $d(x,y)$ in a metric on $X$.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $d_a(x,y)=7|x-y|$ and $d_b(x,y)=|x+y|$ be metrics on set $X$. Show that $d(x,y)=d_a(x,y) + d_b(x,y)$ is also a metric on $X$.

Would I be correct in writing $d_a(x,y) + d_b(x,y)$ as $7|x-y| + |x+y|$? And then applying the regular properties of a metric? If this is the case then how would we prove the triangle inequality?

Comment: You would be correct.  How would you prove the triangle inequality for each of $d_a$ and $d_b$?  When you add their equations, do you get the equation for $d_a + d_b$?

Comment: Ok, so adding the equations would give $2|x-z|+2|z-y| + |x+z| + |z+y|$. But this isn't $d_a+d_b$?

Comment: What kind of set $X$? And what does $|w|$ mean?  Note that if $X$ is a set of reals, or complexes, then $|x+y|$ is not a metric. The distance from $x$ to $x$ is not $0$ in general. Please check exact wording.

Answer (score 5):

This is NOT even a metric, in fact even $d_b(x,y)$ is NOT a metric.

$$0=d_b(x,y) := |x+y| \iff x=-y$$

Comment: Ohh I see, $d_b$ fails the second property of defining a metric. Thank you. Out of curiousity, if we didn't define $d_a$ or $d_b$, then how would I prove that the addition of two metrics is also a metric?

Answer (score 2):

In response to the previous comment in my other answer, I will show that the sum of two metrics $(d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y))$ defines a metric ($d(x,y) = d_1(x,y)+d_2(x,y))$

Proof:
Suppose $d(x,y)=0$ then
$$d(x,y) = d_1(x,y) + d_2(x,y) = 0$$
As $d_1$ and $d_2$ are metrics, they must satisfy $d_1(x,y),d_2(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $x,y \in X$.  But this means that they must be precisely zero, but metrics only equal zero when their arguments are equal, hence $x=y$.

Conversely, suppose $x=y$, then $d_1(x,y)=d_2(x,y)=0$ because these are metrics, hence $d(x,y)=0$.

Symmetry,

$$d(x,y) = d_1(x,y) + d_2(x,y) = d_2(y,x)+d_1(y,x)=d(y,x)$$

where the middle equals sign is true because $d_1, d_2$ are metrics and hence symmetric in their own right.

Triangle Inequality

$$d(x,z) = d_1(x,z) + d_2(x,z) \le [d_1(x,y) + d_1(y,z)] + [d_2(x,y) + d_2(y,z)]=$$ $$=[d_1(x,y) + d_2(x,y)] + [d_1(y,z) + d_2(y,z)]= d(x,y) + d(y,z) $$

where the $\le$ is true because $d_1,d_2$ are metrics and hence satisfy the triangle inequality on their own.

Comment: Read the answer!  I'm assuming IF they are metrics... I know for example that $|4+4| \not \le |4-4|+|-4+4|$

Comment: You did not clarify that.

Comment: I think I was sufficiently clear... because I showed in my other answer that "This is NOT even a metric, in fact even $d_b(x,y)$ is NOT a metric."  In any case, I've changed $d_a$ to $d_1$ and $d_b$ to $d_2$.